# Counting tuples of highly composite numbers whose product is also highly composite

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization, products

I have little experience in number theory. While messing around with highly composite numbers, I came up with the following problem, which I've been unable to solve:

> Let $a, b, c, d$ be a quadruplet of highly composite numbers greater-than 1. Do there exist infinitely many of these quadruplets such that the product $abcd$ is also highly composite?

It seems natural to ask about general $k$-tuples with $k>1$. I strongly suspect that it holds for pairs, because I think there are infinitely many highly composite numbers $N$ such that $2N$ is also highly composite, but I haven't been able to prove or find existing results for even this much.

Is this a well-known or relatively easy problem? Do we know for what $k$ this holds? If it's known to be finite, is there a known expression for how many such tuples there are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt to fill in a justification for Will's claim that "half of it is also an SHC number":

Note that $\left\lfloor\frac{1}{p^{\delta}-1}\right\rfloor = 0$ for  $p > 2^{\frac{1}{\delta}}$, and so we only consider primes $2 < p \le 2^{\frac{1}{\delta}}$. Since $\frac{1}{p^{\delta}-1}$ is an integer iff $p=2$, there must exist some $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ such that for $2 < p \le 2^{\frac{1}{\delta}}$ we have $\left\{\frac{1}{p^{\delta}-1}\right\} > \epsilon$, where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$. To construct $N$ such that $N=\frac{1}{2}W_{\delta}$, we choose some ​$c>0$ such that for all $p \le 2^{\frac{1}{\delta}}$ we have

$$\frac{1}{p^{\delta}-1} - \frac{1}{p^{\delta+c}-1}<\epsilon$$

Now, note that $\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2^{\delta+c}-1} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{1}{2^{\delta}-1}\right\rfloor - 1$, and for $p>2$ we have $\left\lfloor\frac{1}{p^{\delta+c}-1} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{1}{p^{\delta}-1} \right\rfloor$. Hence

$$N=\prod_p p^{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{p^{\delta+c}-1} \right\rfloor} = \frac{1}{2}W_{\delta}$$

Comment: In case of interest, http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/hcnrevisited.pdf  I admit to ignoring the possible trouble,  in case it is possible to have, for some odd prime $p,$  positive integers $j,k$  with $$  \frac{ \log{1 + \frac{1}{j}}}{\log 2} =    \frac{ \log{1 + \frac{1}{k}}}{\log p} $$  which is very unlikely... Seems to me this can be confirmed for a single specified value of $j,$   because of inequalities

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for the reference. If this assumption is true for distinct primes p,q and integers j,k, then might it be possible to extend the result to pairs of SHC numbers (n, pn) for any prime p? I don’t immediately see anywhere in the argument where this would break down

Comment: Daniel, you are exactly correct, any prime. I am not so sure about the original question for three highly composite number. I had concluded last night that this meant both some  number $N$   and $N/12$  both be SHC, less clear than $2.$  Of course, HC numbers are more frequent, perhaps it is easy to prove things when $N$ and $N/12$  are just HC; first thing would be a computer search, best to take a long list of HC numbers from OEIS and look for pairs    https://oeis.org/A002182  and    https://oeis.org/A002182/b002182.txt

Comment: wrote that program, first few HC pairs n and 12n  
1:  1  12 \\ 
2:  2  24 \\ 
3:  4  48 \\ 
4:  60  720 \\ 
5:  840  10080 \\ 
6:  1260  15120 \\ 
7:  1680  20160 \\ 
8:  27720  332640 \\ 
9:  55440  665280 \\ 
10:  720720  8648640 \\ 
11:  1441440  17297280 \\ 
12:  3603600  43243200 \\ 
13:  61261200  735134400 \\ 
14:  183783600  2205403200 \\ 
15:  2327925600  27935107200 \\ 
16:  3491888400  41902660800 \\ 
17:  80313433200  963761198400 \\ 
18:  160626866400  1927522396800 \\ 
19:  1124388064800  13492656777600 \\ 
20:  2248776129600  26985313555200 \\

Answer (score 0):

Just the case of multiplying by 2. For any integer $k \geq 3,$  construct positive real number
$$ \delta = \frac{\log \left(1 + \frac{1}{k} \right)}{\log 2}.  $$

Then construct the superior highly composite number

$$ W_\delta = \prod_p \; p^{\left\lfloor \frac{1}{p^\delta - 1} \right\rfloor  } $$

Then $W_\delta $ is an even integer and half of it is also an SHC  number.

Therefore, take your $$ N = \frac{1}{2}  W_\delta \; \; , $$
both $N$ and $2N$ are highly composite.